# How to send message from Website loaded inside ElectronJs App

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, desktop, electron-builder

I want to create a bridge between electronJS - Native Desktop to WebApp render. I am able successfully send message from WebApp to ElectornJs App using contextBridge using below code,

My question is how to send message from Native App to WebApp. Basically WebApp should have some kind of listener or something like that.

Any help in this regard will be appreciated. thanks

I am able successfully send message from WebApp to ElectornJs App using contextBridge using below code,

ElectronJS Native App `preload.js`-

```
    contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    "api", {
        send: (channel, data) => {
            // whitelist channels
            let validChannels = validChannelsSend
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                ipcRenderer.send(channel, data);
            }
        },
        receive: (channel, func) => {
            let validChannels = validChannelsReceive
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender` 
                ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, data) => {func(data)});
            }
        }
    }
    );
```

In above example window.api.send is working fine to send message from web to native

However opposite is not working . Sending message from native top window.api.receive() api

WebApp - [www.webapp.com](http://www.webapp.com) which load inside electronJs desktop app
window.api.send('webapp-to-nativeapp', 'sending from Webapp');

My question is how to send message from Native App to WebApp. Basically WebApp should have some kind of listener or something like that.

WebApp is able to send data to native app but i am not able to send data from native app to WebApp.